# Scan Lists of Objects and compare an Object Value

Tags: c#, list, object

For example I have 3 lists (or more):

List1:

> [{store:"store1",item:"item1",price:10},{store:"store1",item:"item2",price:5},{store:"store1",item:"item4",price:100},{store:"store1",item:"item10",price:10}]

List2:

> [{store:"store2",item:"item1",price:15},{store:"store2",item:"item2",price:10},{store:"store2",item:"item10",price:110}]

List3:

> [{store:"store3",item:"item1",price:5},{store:"store3",item:"item2",price:10},{store:"store3",item:"item10",price:100},{store:"store3",item:"item100",price:1}]

As you can see It's like 3 stores with different items and prices. Not all stores have all items so I would like to make a list by comparing the lists and finding the objects that contain "item1" for example and then choose the cheaper price. And also to compare the lists 1 by one (list 1 with list 2 , list 1 with list 3, list 2 with 1 and list 2 with 3). Do I make any sense?

Any answer is appreciated.

I've tried some things but I just cant understand it (and its for 2 stores):

```
var result = (from l1 in store1list join l2 in store2list on l1.Symbol equals l2.Symbol orderby l1.Symbol select new
        {

                          store = l1.store,
                          price = l1.price,
                          item = l1.item

        }).ToList();
```

Comment: What did you try already? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Ill add it to the question

Answer (score 2):

You may Union your lists and then GroupBy item, and select ordering each group with price and taking the first one (cheapest) from each group.

```
var result = List1.Concat(List2).Concat(List3).GroupBy(x => x.item)
     .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x=> x.price).First()).ToList();
```